# Empty array if strings in c# for unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to empty and array of strings every-time a user clicks on load profiles so that the array doesn't get over populated with the same profiles over and over again every time they click load.

This is my array:

```
string[] files;
```

This is how i get the profiles but i need to empty it whenever getProfiles is called so it doesn't over populate with duplicate profiles

```
private void GetProfiles()
{
    //Check if directory with saved profiles exists
    if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
    {
        //Clear files array


        //Get all of the file paths of each file in this directory
        files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
        //profileTileTemplate.SetActive(true);

        //Go through each file and read the data and create a profile for each json file
        for(int i = 1; i <= files.Length -1; i++)
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(files[i]);
            Profile savedProfile = JsonUtility.FromJson<Profile>(json);
            Instantiate(profileTileTemplate,LoadProfileTransform);
            profileTileTemplate.SetActive(true);
            profileTileTemplate.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = savedProfile.playerName;
            Debug.Log(savedProfile.playerName);
        }
    }
}
```

how do i clear this array?

I have tried setting it to null but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by clear the array / what exactly doesn't work? Did you maybe also mean to store the instantiated objects somewhere in order to destroy them all ...?

Comment: And not that you are not changing the instantiated object but rather the **prefab** `profileTileTemplate` .. is this supposed to happen?

Comment: And why do you skip the first file in the loop? Indices in `c#` start at `0` not `1` ...

Comment: skipping the first one is temporary and will be changed later. I mean when you click on a button to load the profiles in the game it loads them and adds them to the array every time so if you keep clicking on load profiles i only want it to load them once hence needing to empty the array otherwise every-time they get duplicated

Comment: Why not use a `List<string>` instead and call its [`Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=net-6.0) method when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, but if you want to empty the array and stay with the same length then you can write this wherever you want to.

```
files = new string[files.Length];
```

Comment: Actually `GetFiles` returns a new array anyway so I don't think this is what OP is asking for ..

Comment: @derHugo Yes I saw that, but maybe OP wants to return a new empty array while `GetFiles` returns an array of file paths.

Answer (score 0):

As said I don't think this is related to the array at all .. `GetFiles` everytime returns a new array there are no duplicates.

However, you Instantiate a bunch of objects into the scene and never destroy them!

You could do this first

```
foreach(Transform child in LoadProfileTransform)
{
    Destroy (child.gameObject);
}
```

and then you could simply do

```
foreach(var path in files)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var savedProfile = JsonUtility.FromJson<Profile>(json);
    var obj = Instantiate(profileTileTemplate,LoadProfileTransform);
    obj.SetActive(true);
    obj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = savedProfile.playerName;
    Debug.Log(savedProfile.playerName);
}
```

since you want to apply the text etc to the newly instantiated objects, not the original prefab.